# Compare two dataframes to guess gender (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I've been stuck on a dataframe problem for days now, and I hope you will be able to help me !

I have two dataframes :

- One named `dfCombin`, which contains first names (and many other informations which have no interest at this point) ;
- The other named `dfPrenomsFR` with first names and their gender, which I got on the French government website.

Here is a sample of `dfPrenomsFR` :

```
   Prenom   Genre
0   Aaliyah F
1   Aapeli  M
2   Aapo    M
3   Aaren   M,f
4   Aarne   M
... ... ...
11622   Zvi M
11623   Zvonimir    M
11624   Zvonimira   F
11625   Zvonko  M
11626   Zygmunt M
```

and here is a sample of `dfCombin` :

```
     TITLE              NAME AUTHOR 1    FIRST NAME AUTHOR 1    
0   Accident majeur     Julliard         Jean-François  
1   J'accuse...         Dytar            Jean   
2   Les Mémés farouches Frécon           Sylvain
```

My goal is to see if the first names in `dfCombin` (in the column '*FIRST NAME AUTHOR 1*') are present in the column '*Prenom*' of `dfPrenomsFR`.

If it is the case, I would like to create a new column labelled '*GenreAuteur*' in `dfCombin` which takes the gender value of this first name, which I can find in the column '*Genre*' of `dfPrenomsFR` (which can be either 'M', 'F' or 'M,f').

I also would like to fill the other lines of '*GenreAuteur*' of (which have no gender information) with "NA".

Thank you for your help !!

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['Aaliyah', 'Aapeli', 'Aapo'], 'g':['F','M','M']})
dfCombin = pd.DataFrame({'fna':['Sylvain','Aaliyah']}) 
dfCombin.merge(df, left_on='fna', right_on='name', how='left')[['fna','g']]
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. Unfortunately, I only have 'NaN' values when using this technique...

Comment: As you can see from the example it works. Possible way is that there is no intersection or some kinds of inconstancy such blank before names in one of the columns. can you share part of your data for more analysis?

Comment: Hello, you were right, there was a blank space before the first names of dfCombin.

Comment: Yes ! Thank you for the idea of using "merge". I had to modify it a little, but it was the right way to follow :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following to find the names in `dfPrenomsFr` that are also in `dfCombin`:

```
import numpy as np
intersection = np.intersect1d(dfPrenomsFR.Prenom, dfCombin['FIRST NAME AUTHOR 1'])
```

And select the gender of these names and assign it to a new column:

```
dfCombin['GenreAuteur'] = dfPrenomsFR.loc[dfPrenomsFR.Prenom.isin(intersection).index, 'Genre']
```

Comment: Hello, this is not working either, it says that all names are males...